# paint several x,y series of values in one with matplotlib in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two lists like the following:

```
values = [['2000', '246', '535', '461', '654', '522'], ['2000', '246', '535', '461', '654']]
levels = [['Levels', '200', '300', '400', '500', '600'], ['Levels', '200', '350', '430', '520']]
```

The idea is to represent in the same graph, starting from the second position of each list, the first list of `values` against the first list of `elements` and the second list of `values` against the second list of `levels`.

For it I put the following lines of code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)

for i in range(0,len(levels)):
   x=values[i]
   y=levels[i]
   x1=x[1:]
   y1=y[1:]
   ax.plot(x1,y1)

plt.show()
```

But with this I am obtaining two different graphs. How would I be able to represent everything in one graph? Thanks!

Comment: [It all plots on the same graph for me...](http://i.imgur.com/sSGVPmE.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example code seems to do what you want...

You could make it a little more pythonic though;

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)

allValues = [['2000', '246', '535', '461', '654', '522'], ['2000', '246', '535', '461', '654']]
allLevels = [['Levels', '200', '300', '400', '500', '600'], ['Levels', '200', '350', '430', '520']]

for levels, values in zip(allLevels, allValues):
  ax.plot(levels[1:],values[1:])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Also, and just a guess, but have you got `x` and `y` the wrong way around?

Comment: it works! it is true that my code also worked, but I do not know what I was doing bad before. The levels should be in the ordinate axis to do the graph I want! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop "for" to make you want. Try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)

x = values[0][1:] + values[1][1:]
y = levels[0][1:] + levels[1][1:]

ax.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but I cannot mix in this way the data, because each of those curves has a particular colour, legend and so on. If I mix the data then I lose this information. This is why I thought about looping.